# C++ equivalent of MATLAB's "fileparts" function

Tags: c++, matlab, file-io

In MATLAB there's a nice function called fileparts that takes a full file path and parses it into path, filename (without extension), and extension as in the following example from the documentation:

```
file = 'H:\user4\matlab\classpath.txt';

[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(file)

>> pathstr = H:\user4\matlab

>> name = classpath

>> ext = .txt
```

So I was wondering if there's an equivalent function in any standard C++ or C libraries that I could use? Or would I have to implement this myself? I realize it's fairly simple, but I figured if there's already something pre-made that would be preferable.

Thanks.

Comment: These functions exist, but they're part of the OS library, not the C++ standard.  The C++ standard doesn't say very much about filenames at all.  What OS are you using?

Comment: [`basename(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dirname.3.html). Not exactly what you are looking for, but something.

Comment: Then the functions I listed should help, they're all for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible solutions, depending on your OS:

- Visual C++ [_splitpath function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx)
- Win32 [Shell Path Handling Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559.aspx) such as `PathFindExtension`, `PathFindFileName`, `PathStripPath`, `PathRemoveExtension`, `PathRemoveFileSpec`

Answer (score 5):

The boost library has a [file system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm) component "basic_path" that allows you use iterators to discover each component in the filename. Such a component would be OS specific, and I believe you need to compile boost separately for Windows, Linux etc.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote this simple function. It behaves similar as Matlab's `fileparts` and works independent of platform.

```
struct FileParts
{
    string path;
    string name;
    string ext;
};

FileParts fileparts(string filename)
{
    int idx0 = filename.rfind("/");
    int idx1 = filename.rfind(".");

    FileParts fp;
    fp.path = filename.substr(0,idx0+1);
    fp.name = filename.substr(idx0+1,idx1-idx0-1);
    fp.ext  = filename.substr(idx1);

    return fp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A platform-independent way with C++11/14.

```
#include <experimental/filesystem> 

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
void fileparts(string full, string& fpath, string& fname, string& fext)
{
    auto source = fs::path(full);
    fpath = source.parent_path().string();
    fname = source.stem().string();
    fext = source.extension().string();
}
...
string fpath, fname, fext;
fileparts(full_file_path,fpath,fname,fext);
```

Comment: `<filesystem>` is part of the C++17 standard. Works like above, but remove all the `experimental` bits.

Answer (score 1):

Ekalic's text-only approach is useful, but it didn't check for errors. Here's one that does, and also works with both / and \

```
struct FileParts
{
    std::string path; //!< containing folder, if provided, including trailing slash
    std::string name; //!< base file name, without extension
    std::string ext;  //!< extension, including '.'
};

//! Using only text manipulation, splits a full path into component file parts
FileParts fileparts(const std::string &fullpath)
{
    using namespace std;

    size_t idxSlash = fullpath.rfind("/");
    if (idxSlash == string::npos) {
        idxSlash = fullpath.rfind("\\");
    }
    size_t idxDot = fullpath.rfind(".");

    FileParts fp;
    if (idxSlash != string::npos && idxDot != string::npos) {
        fp.path = fullpath.substr(0, idxSlash + 1);
        fp.name = fullpath.substr(idxSlash + 1, idxDot - idxSlash - 1);
        fp.ext  = fullpath.substr(idxDot);
    } else if (idxSlash == string::npos && idxDot == string::npos) {
        fp.name = fullpath;
    } else if (/* only */ idxSlash == string::npos) {
        fp.name = fullpath.substr(0, idxDot);
        fp.ext  = fullpath.substr(idxDot);
    } else { // only idxDot == string::npos
        fp.path = fullpath.substr(0, idxSlash + 1);
        fp.name = fullpath.substr(idxSlash + 1);
    }
    return fp;
}
```